# Temporary Tables

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have four tables and I have to bring those tables into a temporary table and loop through temporary table to delete data how can I do through stored procedure.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: How can I edit no edit option

Comment: This is not a question, but a task for a freelancer..

Comment: Hi it is just a question asked.

Comment: Take the tutorial to have enough "reputation" to edit.

Comment: Do you really need a temp table?  What is the `INSERT...SELECT` that you will use to fill the temp table.  With that, we can help you use a "derived table" to do the `DELETE`.  Or, more likely, a multi-table `DELETE`.